# Linearlayout should not cut off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

sorry for this newbie question. I have googled a while and cannot find an answer.

I have 10 buttons in a row. This looks ok on my tablet. But when I start the app on my phone only the first 5 buttons are shown, the rest is cut off.

If there is not enough space the remaining buttons should be displayed in a second row. How can I do that?

Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="9"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10"
    />
```

Comment: i don't think there is an easy way of doing that.

Comment: a gridview, may be, but your buttons would all be the same side.

Comment: Use "ScrollView" and put your LinearLayout into scrollView - [example](http://mojdroid.pl/4731/10-tworz-aplikacje-na-androida-z-mojdroid-pl-scrollview)

Comment: when I use GridView, shall I use Button or ImageView inside GridView?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting!  take `scrollview` parents of `LinearLayout`@

```
<ScrollView...
<LinearLayout...//android:orientation="horizontal"
<Button... // your all buttons
</Button>  
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5"
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="9"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Place all your buttons into a `GridView` - this will work across any screen size and is relatively straightforward and neat.
2. Put them into a `ScrollView`. This is quite popular but a bit annoying for the user as it can lead to mis-clicks and they may not realise you can scroll the buttons.
3. If you only ever want exactly 1 or 2 rows depending on screen size, put each row of buttons into a separate layout file. Then create 2 additoinal screen-dependent layouts containing `LinearLayout` which include both rows, but give the portrait version a vertical orientation. So when that layout is loaded, you get two rows.
4. Work out if you can present the buttons in a different way - maybe using just icons, or combine them into dropdowns.

Comment: Hello, when I use GridView, shall I use Button or ImageView inside GridView?

Comment: If they're text buttons, used `Button`. If they're buttons consisting of one image, use `ImageButton`. If they just images - aren't aren't meant to be touched/clicked - use `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:text="10"/>
</LinearLayout>
```